# How to display and get directions with A*

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have a Pathfinding algorithm which is working but the problem is that i can't get the directions on my main class. in other words every time i wan't to display the directions it output null values.

here's my code.

Astar.java

```
package path;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import path.Node.Directions;
import map.Area;

public class Astar {

    public ArrayList<Node> open;
    public ArrayList<Node> closed;
    public Area area;
    public Node start;
    public Node finish;

    public Astar() {
        this.area = new Area(5, 5);
        this.start = new Node(1, 1, area);
        this.finish = new Node(4, 4, area);
        this.open = new ArrayList<Node>();
        this.closed = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    public void calculate() {

        start.distanceFromStart = 0;
        closed.clear();
        open.clear();
        open.add(start);
        Node current = null;

        while (open.size() != 0) {
            current = open.get(0);
            if (current.equals(finish)) {
                break;
            }
            open.remove(current);
            closed.add(current);
            for (Node n : current.getNeighborsList()) {
                boolean neighborIsBetter;

                if (closed.contains(n))
                    continue;

                if (!n.isObstacle) {
                    double neighborDistanceFromStart = current.distanceFromStart + getDistanceBetween(current, n);
                    if (!open.contains(n)) {
                        open.add(n);
                        Collections.sort(open);
                        neighborIsBetter = true;
                    }
                    else if (neighborDistanceFromStart < current.distanceFromStart)
                        neighborIsBetter = true;
                    else
                        neighborIsBetter = false;
                    if (neighborIsBetter) {
                        n.parent = current;
                        searchPath(current);
                        n.distanceFromStart = neighborDistanceFromStart;
                        n.heuristicDistanceFromGoal = getEstimatedDistanceToGoal(n, finish);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Distance from start: " + neighborDistanceFromStart);
                }
                else if(n.isObstacle){
                    closed.add(n);
                }

            }

        }
        if (current != null)
            reconstructPath(current);
    }
    public void searchPath(Node node){

        System.out.printf("\nNode: (%d, %d)\n", node.x, node.y);

    }

    public void reconstructPath(Node node) {

        while (!(node.parent == null)) {
            System.out.printf("\nNode: (%d, %d)\n", node.x, node.y);
            node = node.parent;

        }
    }

    private double getDistanceBetween(Node n1, Node n2) {
        if ((n1.x == n2.x) || (n1.y == n2.y))
            return 1;
        else
            return 1.9;
    }

    private double getEstimatedDistanceToGoal(Node start, Node finish) {
        //Manhattan Calculation closest heuristic
        double dx = start.x - finish.x;
        double dy = start.y - finish.y;
        return dx + dy;

    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Astar astar = new Astar();
        astar.calculate();
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

Node.java

```
package path;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import map.Area;

public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    public boolean isClosed;
    public boolean isGoal;
    public boolean isObstacle;
    public boolean isVisited;
    public boolean isStart;
    public Node parent;
    public Node north;
    public Node south;
    public Node east;
    public Node west;

    public Area map;

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public double heuristicDistanceFromGoal;
    public double distanceFromStart;

    public enum Directions {
        NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST
    };

    public Node(int x, int y, Area map) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.isVisited = false;
        this.distanceFromStart = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        this.isObstacle = false;
        this.isStart = false;
        this.isGoal = false;
        this.map = map;
    }

    public boolean equals(Node node) {
        return (this.x == node.x) && (this.y == node.y);
    }

    public void setNode(Directions dir, Node node) {
        Node temp = getDirectionalNode(dir);
        ArrayList<Node> list = this.getNeighborsList();
        if (list.contains(temp))
            list.remove(temp);
        list.add(node);
        setDirectionalNode(dir, node);
    }

    public Node getDirectionalNode(Directions dir) {    
        switch (dir) {
            case NORTH:
                return north;
            case SOUTH:
                return south;
            case EAST:
                return east;
            case WEST:
                return west;        
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setDirectionalNode(Directions dir, Node node) { 
        switch (dir) {
            case NORTH:
                this.north = node;
            case SOUTH:
                this.south = node;
            case EAST:
                this.east = node;
            case WEST:
                this.west = node;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getNeighborsList() {
        ArrayList<Node> neighborList = new ArrayList<Node>();

        if (!(y == (map.height + 1))) {
            neighborList.add(map.getNode(x, y + 1));
        }

        return neighborList;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node other) {
        double totalDistanceFromGoal = this.distanceFromStart - this.heuristicDistanceFromGoal;
        double otherDistanceFromGoal = other.distanceFromStart - other.heuristicDistanceFromGoal;
        if (totalDistanceFromGoal < otherDistanceFromGoal)
            return -1;
        if (otherDistanceFromGoal > totalDistanceFromGoal)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Area.java

```
package map;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import path.Node;

public class Area {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> map;

    public Area(int w, int h) {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;

        createMap();

    }

    public Node getNode(int x, int y) {
        return map.get(y).get(x);
    }

    private void createMap() {
        Node node;
        map = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>>();
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            map.add(new ArrayList<Node>());
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                node = new Node(x, y, this);
                map.get(y).add(node);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

output:

```
Traceback: (4, 4) Traceback: (4, 3) Traceback: (4, 2) 
Traceback: (4, 1) Traceback: (3, 1)Traceback: (2, 1)
```

Problem: No directions: I get null when i call node.north

Comment: No one is going to go through all this code, provide only the minimal required part to understand the problem. Also, describe what you have already done (and explain your algorithm), and then explain what is still missing. Providing an example is usually helpful as well.

Comment: i did post all of this code in order to locate the nodes direction from the Node class to the Astar Class. example. System.out.println("Direction: " + n.east); OUTPUT: NULL. my problem is how to show what's the direction of the parent node. if i won't post the code you will not be able to answer my problem. All i want is get the current nodes direction and display it on the main class which is astar

Comment: What I have so far is this:
Node: (1, 1)
null
Distance from start: 1.0

Node: (2, 1)
null
Distance from start: 2.0

Node: (2, 2)
null
Distance from start: 3.0

Node: (3, 2)
null
Distance from start: 4.0

Node: (3, 3)
null
Distance from start: 5.0

Node: (4, 3)
null
Distance from start: 6.0

What i want is to know if 2.1 is in the north, east or west. I am able to get the shortest path

Answer (score 0):

```
public Node parent;
public Node north;
public Node south;
public Node east;
public Node west;

public enum Directions {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST
};
```

This seems just strange. I guess you wanted to do this:

```
public Node parent;
public Direction north;
public Direction south;
public Direction east;
public Direction west;

public enum Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST
};
```

The whole thing confuses me a little, you never set the bearing. Nodes usually don't have a direction.
If you want the direction that the current avatar took from the last node to the current node. So its bearing basically.
This might help?
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219235009/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55417.html)

Comment: Just thought of it. Now I get what you wanted with the Nodes in each direction. Sorry was a little confused.

Comment: Yes sir you got it right. you really got my point. Sir I got errors when i try to change public node north to public direction north

Comment: If you want my whole code sir I can show you. just please help me sir its my project. It's making me crazy i've been debugging this for 8 hours

Comment: I am not sure what you want to accomplish. What I wrote is wrong (forget public direction north) but you want to calculate if a node is north or south or west of your current node and then set it to that variable. Then you have a graph with nodes that have saved which other nodes are in which direction. I don't understand the reason behind it.
Or do you want to save in what direction from start the current Node is?
Where do you call setDirectionalNode and what for?